# SwiftUI: Binding on property of struct derived from environment object

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, observableobject, environmentobject

I have two structs in my task manager app:

```swift
struct Task {
    var identifier: String
    var title: String
    var tags: [String] // Array of tag identifiers
}
struct Tag {
    var identifier: String
    var title: String
}
```

I then have a class to store them:

```swift
class TaskStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [String:Task]()
    @Published var tags = [String:Tag]()
}
```

which I pass to my root view as an `.environmentObject(taskStore)`.

Correct me if any of the following is wrong (against bad practices):

In my `TaskView` I have:

```swift
    @EnvironmentObject var taskStore: TaskStore

    var taskIdentifier: String // Passed from parent view

    private var task: Task {
        get {
            return taskStore.tasks[taskIdentifier]! // Looks up the task in the store
        }
    }
    private var tags: [Tag] {
        get {
            return taskStore.tags
        }
    }
```

The issue is, when learning SwiftUI I was told when making certain components (like a picker that let's you alter the tags array in this case) that it should accept a binding to the value/collection, or say I want to make the task title editable, I need a binding to the `task.title` property, both of which I can't do because (based on the way I'm defining and computing `task`) I can't get a binding on `task`.

Am I doing something against best practices here? Or where along this path did I diverge from the right way of storing points of truth in an environment object, and make them editable in sub views.

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You most likely don't need the computed variable. Post the code for the view where you want to use it. Regardless, NEVER use the `!` in that way as you are inviting a crash.

Comment: +1 to what others have said, you need to provide us more context, for us to be able to give relevant advices: how are you using the view, and how the view makes use of the properties in discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not necessarily doing something against best practices. I think in SwiftUI, the concepts of data model storage and manipulation quickly become more complex than, for example, what Apple tends to show in its demo code. With a real app, with a single source of truth, like you seem to be using, you're going to have to come up with some ways to bind the data to your views.

One solution is to write `Binding`s with your own `get` and `set` properties that interact with your `ObservableObject`. That might look like this, for example:

```
struct TaskView : View {
    var taskIdentifier: String // Passed from parent view
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var taskStore: TaskStore
    
    private var taskBinding : Binding<Task> {
        Binding {
            taskStore.tasks[taskIdentifier] ?? .init(identifier: "", title: "", tags: [])
        } set: {
            taskStore.tasks[taskIdentifier] = $0
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Task title", text: taskBinding.title)
    }
}
```

If you're averse to this sort of thing, one way to avoid it is to use CoreData. Because the models are made into `ObservableObject`s by the system, you can generally avoid this sort of thing and directly pass around and manipulate your models. However, that doesn't necessarily mean that it is the right (or better) choice either.

You may also want to explore [TCA](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture) which is an increasingly popular state management and view binding library that provides quite a few built-in solutions for the type of thing you're looking at doing.

Comment: This. This is exactly what I was trying to do. I was close in that I had a @State var that I was trying to update with a custom binding, but unable to access `self` in the get of the Binding. Didn't even think to just bind to the underlying task in the store. Doh! Thank you!

Comment: these bindings have perf penalties. watch latest wwdc vid on swiftui perf.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to model your data with value types and manage lifecycle and side-effects with a reference type. The bit you are missing is that Task doesn't implement the `Identifiable` protocol which enables SwiftUI to keep track of the data in a `List` or `ForEach`. Implement that as follows:

```
struct Task: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var tags: [String] // Array of tag identifiers
}
```

Then switch to using an array, e.g.

```
class TaskStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
    @Published var tags = [Tag]()

    // you might find this helper found in Fruta useful
    func task(for identifier: String) -> Task? {
        return tasks.first(where: { $0.id == identifier })
    }
}
```

Now that you have an array of identifiable data it is real simple to get a binding to the task via:

```
List($model.tasks) { $task in 
    // now you have a binding to the task
}
```

I recommend checking out [Apple's Fruta sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui) for more detail.